# Is there an R function for returning shared values in most but not all vectors?

Tags: r

I have 4 vectors and I want to do a somewhat lenient intersect where I accept values present in at least three of them. So for example:

```
f1 <- c("apple", "pear")
f2 <- c("apple", "banana")
f3 <- c("apple", "pear", "orange")
f4 <- c("apple", "pear", "tomato")

lenient-intersect(f1, f2, f3, f4)
"apple" "pear"
```

is there such a function as lenient-intersect, where it will return values present in some number of input vectors? Is there an easier way of doing this than intersecting every combination of 2 vectors and doing a series of if statements?

Comment: If they are dataframes, maybe you need some sort of *join?

Comment: I don't think there's such a function, but you could probably write one yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple function that you can use

```
lenient_intersect <- function(times, ...) {
  x <- table(unlist(lapply(list(...), unique)))
  names(x[x>=times])
}
lenient_intersect(3, f1, f2, f3, f4)
lenient_intersect(4, f1, f2, f3, f4)
```

I just added a parameter for the minimum number of times you want it to appear